# Combing related data from two different sources in a single Gatsby page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm creating a blog where each blog page will show a map using leaflet with a GPX route on it. Below the map will be some statistics and some text and images.

I have the text and images part defined in mark down so i figured the way to handle this would be to define my gpx filename in the frontmatter like so:

```
---
title: Awesome Blog Post Title
author: Cancrizan
date: 2021-01-04
gpxFile: activity4835702422
---
BLOG POST here
```

where the field gpxFile refers to a a file in my project `src/gpx/activity4835702422.gpx`.

I've written a transformer plugin that will read in the GPX file so that it can be queried like this:

```
query MyQuery {
  allActivity4835702422Gpx {
    edges {
      node {
        geometry {
          coordinates
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and outputs something like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allActivity4835702422Gpx": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "geometry": {
              "coordinates": [
                [
                  -1.2134187016636133,
                  52.92038678191602,
                  29.399999618530273
                ],
                [
                  -1.2134256586432457,
                  52.92039977386594,
                  29.399999618530273
                ],
                ...,
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

I want to access that node based on the frontmatter of the markdown file and i'm not sure how?

Can anyone suggest a solution or am i going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

The structure and the mindset you've followed is perfectly valid, the only part you're missing is to pass the `gpxFile` to your template in order to create another query based on that parameter.

Your `gatsby-node.js` should look like something like this:

```
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const result = await graphql(
    `
      {
        allMarkdownRemark(limit: 1000) {
          edges {
            node {
              frontmatter {
                title
                author
                date
                gpxFile
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`)
    return
  }

  const postTemplate= path.resolve(`src/templates/post.js`);

  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    const path = node.frontmatter.path
    createPage({
       path: `/posts/${node.frontmatter.slug}`,
       component: postTemplate,
       context: {
         gpxFile: node.frontmatter.gpxFile,
         path: node.frontmatter.slug
       }
    })
  })
}
```

The idea is to use context API to pass data (`gpxFileData` and `path`) to your template (`postTemplate`) to use it as a filter for your markdown files.

In your `postTemplate`, your query should look like:

```
export const postData = graphql`
    query getArticleData($path: String!, $gpxFile: String) {
        post: markdownRemark (fields: {frontmatter: { slug: { eq: $path }}}) {
            html
            excerpt (pruneLength: 350)
            frontmatter {
              title
              author
              date
              gpxFile
              slug
            }
        }
        gpxFileData: allFile(relativePath: { in: $gpxFile })
           # your gpx data here
        }
    }
`;
```

It's quite self-explanatory, basically, you are passing via context the necessary data to make a query in your template (`gpxFileData`) from your `gatsby-node.js`. There, you can create a new query, `allFile`, filtering by `relativePath` (you may need to access to `file` directly or use `absolutePath`, test it in `localhost:8000/___graphql`) and retrieve the whole data using `props.data.post` and `post.data.gpxFileData`.

Disclaimer: I'm assuming that you've set your filesystem (`gatsby-source-filesystem`) properly to use `allFile` across your `.gpx` files.

Comment: Thanks Ferran, your answer pointed me in the right direction. As you suggested i've passed the GPX file name through the context so it can be used as a variable in the template query!

Comment: I'm glad to help @RSmith . If the issue has been solved please consider accepting/upvote the answer to close the issue :)